# AddHandler to ToolStripMenuItem through ContextMenuStrip.Opening event not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi to you all and Merry Christmas.

I have recently inherited a VB projects that I must add functionality. So I have the code below:

```
    Private Sub AddItems()
        Dim itemMenu = DirectCast(ContextMenuStrip.Items.Find("name", False)(0), ToolStripMenuItem)

        For Each dbObject In dbObjects
            Dim item As New ToolStripMenuItem(dbObject.Name)
            item.Tag = dbObject
            AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf Item_Click
            itemMenu.DropDownItems.Add(item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveItems()
        Dim itemMenu = DirectCast(ContextMenuStrip.Items.Find("name", False)(0), ToolStripMenuItem)

        For Each item As ToolStripItem In itemMenu.DropDownItems
            RemoveHandler item.Click, AddressOf Item_Click
        Next

        itemMenu.DropDownItems.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_Opening(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip.Opening
        AddItems()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_Closing(sender As Object, e As ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip.Closing
        RemoveItems()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Do the work            
    End Sub
```

The logic is to fill a sub-menu in a context menu each time with valid database objects.

The problem is that this code does not work. It adds the items to context menu perfectly but the `AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf Item_Click` does nothing.

The strange thing is that if I call the `AddItems()` in `Form_Load` then it works perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

**2016.12.22 Solution after WozzeC answer**

```
    Private Sub AddItems()
        RemoveItems()
        Dim itemMenu = DirectCast(ContextMenuStrip.Items.Find("name", False)(0), ToolStripMenuItem)

        For Each dbObject In dbObjects
            Dim item As New ToolStripMenuItem(dbObject.Name)
            item.Tag = dbObject
            AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf Item_Click
            itemMenu.DropDownItems.Add(item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveItems()
        Dim itemMenu = DirectCast(ContextMenuStrip.Items.Find("name", False)(0), ToolStripMenuItem)

        For Each item As ToolStripItem In itemMenu.DropDownItems
            RemoveHandler item.Click, AddressOf Item_Click
        Next

        itemMenu.DropDownItems.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ContextMenuStrip_Opening(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip.Opening
        AddItems()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Do the work            
    End Sub
```

Comment: The `ToolStripMenuItem` constructor has overloads that take a `Click` event handler so I'd suggest using that instead.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the response. This does not work either. Still searching but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been playing around with this for a little while now and I have managed to reproduce your issue. The reason for your headache is that RemoveItems fires before your Click event. So when you perform RemoveHandler, the click event disappear.

What I suggest that you do instead is to not add the click handler on the ContextMenuItems. Instead you add an EventHandler for DropDownItemClicked on the Parent node. The result will be the same as if Item.Click worked, but without the headache of handling Handlers dynamically.

I also tried switching from Closing to Closed event on the ContextMenu for RemoveItems. But to no avail I am afraid.

Another way to solve this issue is by moving RemoveItems into the first row of AddItems. Then you remove the closing event and its call to RemoveItems. This means that whenever you want to create a new ContextMenu the previous one is disposed properly. This will also solve your future bug where the ContextMenu items are added twice or more. Which currently happens for you if you right click multiple times really fast.

Comment: You are right. The problem was that `ContextMenuStrip_Closing` was triggered before the `Item_Click`. The solution is to call `RemoveItems` at the beginning of `AddItems`. Thanks a lot and Merry Christmas my friend.